# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore most of the time doesn't save data

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am struggled at saving data to `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`. Sometimes happened that data are not completely saved. Sometimes it works fine.

Code to save data in an app:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.set(true, forKey: "Key")
```

Code to get data from an app:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.bool(forKey: "Key")
```